# Provide a Venn diagram of a counter example of the converse of if A ⊆ B, then A ∪ C ⊆ B ∪ C?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Provide a Venn diagram of a counter example of the converse of

$$A \subseteq B\rightarrow ((A \cup C) \subseteq (B \cup C))$$

Comment: Expecting us to make a drawing for you is not really reasonable.

Comment: Take $C$ to be some set not intersecting $A$ or $B$, then the right side is always true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, we need to clearly state the converse of

$$ (A ⊆ B) \rightarrow [(A ∪ C) ⊆ (B ∪ C)].\tag 1$$

The converse of $(1)$ is as follows:

$$[(A ∪ C) ⊆ (B ∪ C)]\rightarrow (A\subseteq B)\tag{2}$$

One counterexample to the converse (2):  $$\text{Suppose } \;A = \{1\}, \;B=\{2\}, \;C=\{1,2\}$$

Then, it is true that $((A ∪ C) = C) ⊆ ((B ∪ C) = C)$ but $A\not \subseteq B$ because $\{1\} \not \subseteq \{2\}$

Comment: Thanks! Great explanation! I got it right!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

For example, suppose that $A\subset C$ and $B\subset C$, and $A $ is not a subset of $B$.

For instance, suppose $A=\{a\}$, $B=\{b\}$ with $a\neq b$ and $C=\{a,b\}$.

Comment: This works! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's take subsets of $\Bbb{R}$:
$A=(0,1)$, $B=(1,2)$ and $C=(0,2)$, for example.

Answer (score -1):

Consider  when B is a proper subset of A is a proper subset of C.

Comment: If you ever bothered to typeset your answers correctly, then there's a **really** nice way to communicate what you are trying to say